# Shuttle getting stuck to the net after crossing

Tags: rules, badminton

I've never seen this happen before but it happened twice in one game recently (by 2 different players!).

The shuttle hit the tape and went over the net but then got caught and never hit the ground.

None of us were sure what the rules said on this one.
Does the shuttle have to hit the ground before anyone wins the point?

We played it as a let but I wondered what the official line was on this one.

Does it matter whether this happens during serve or mid rally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According the official *[LAWS OF BADMINTON](http://bwfbadminton.org/file.aspx?id=516821&dl=1)*, set by the [Badminton World Federation](http://bwfbadminton.org/default.aspx), chapter 14 is affected: *LETS*. Here the different situations are outlined when you need to play a let and in paragraph 14.2.3 [the following about that is mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhXBM.png):

> **14. LETS**
>
> - 14.1 ‘Let’ shall be called by the umpire, or by a player (if there is no umpire), to halt play.
> - 14.2 It shall be a ‘let’, if:
>
>   - 14.2.1 the server serves before the receiver is ready (Law 9.4);
>   - 14.2.2 during service, the receiver and the server are both faulted;
>   - 14.2.3 after the service is returned, the shuttle is:
>
>     - 14.2.3.1 caught on the net and remains suspended on its top, or
>     - 14.2.3.2 after passing over the net is caught on the net;

From your description, it seems as if the second subparagraph is applicable: 14.2.3.2.

As to your second question, it does matter when it happens. The title of *14.2.3* states that it is only valid, when the service is returned. So, if it were to happen during a backhand low service for example, then a point would be given to your opponent.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it makes a difference whether it's the serve or in general play.

These rules only apply if the shuttle at least gets to the top of the net (or over it) before becoming stuck. If you hit it too low and it gets stuck in the middle of the net without going over first, that's a fault and you lose the point.

> It shall be a ‘fault’:
>
> ....
> 13.2 if, **in service**, the shuttle:
>
> - 13.2.1 is caught on the net and remains suspended on its top;
> - 13.2.2 after passing over the net, is caught in the net; or
> - 13.2.3 is hit by the receiver’s partner;
>
> 14.2 It shall be a ‘let”, if:
>
> ....
> 14.2.3 **after the service is returned**, the shuttle is:
>
> - 14.2.3.1 caught on the net and remains suspended on its top, or
> - 14.2.3.2 after passing over the net is caught in the net;

[Source](http://www.worldbadminton.com/rules/documents/bwfHandbook2010.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

It must be treated as a [let](http://www.angelfire.com/ab2/OxfordBadminton/Rules.html#Lets)

1. 'Let' is called by the umpire, or by a player (if there is no umpire) to halt play.
2. A 'let' may be given for any unforeseen or accidental occurrence.
3. > **If a shuttle is caught on the net and remains suspended on top or, after passing over the net, is caught in the net, it is a 'let' except
   >   on service**.
4. If during service, the receiver and server are both faulted at the same time, it shall be a 'let'.
5. If the server serves before the receiver is ready it shall be a 'let'.
6. If during play, the shuttle disintegrates and the base completely separates from the rest of the shuttle, it shall be a 'let'.
7. If a line judge is unsighted and the umpire is unable to make a decision, it shall be a 'let'.
8. A 'let' may occur following a service court error; see Law 12.3
9. When a 'let' occurs, the play since the last service shall not count and the player who served shall serve again, except where Law 14 is applicable.

Other links supporting the same are :

1. [angelfire.com](http://www.angelfire.com/ab2/OxfordBadminton/Rules.html#Lets)
2. A [yahoo answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080714060318AAOufqE)
3. [badminton-information.com](http://www.badminton-information.com/rules-of-badminton.html)