# How is it a let if the shuttle is caught on/in the net?

Tags: rules, badminton

I am studying the Laws of Badminton. I am concerned about point **14.2.3** under [Law 14 for Lets](http://www.worldbadminton.com/rules/#14). The point states that:

> 14.2.3
>   [It shall be a let, if] after the service is returned, the shuttle is:
>
> - 14.2.3.1
>     caught on the net and remains suspended on its top, or
> - 14.2.3.2
>     after passing over the net is caught in the net;

I understand the first point. In it, the shuttle is stuck on the top white ribbon of the net. In this scenario, the shuttle is most probably oriented base pointed upwards, with its feathers stuck on the white ribbon.

I however fail to understand how the second point represents any scenario other than the first point. If the shuttle "passed over the net", then it means to me that it "has crossed across the net", and therefore can't be "caught" on it!

I need help visualizing the scenario in the second point (14.2.3.2).

Comment: Similar: [Shuttle getting stuck to the net after crossing](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3671/shuttle-getting-stuck-to-the-net-after-crossing/3678)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This let is called if the shuttle tumbles over the net and then gets caught in the net. In this situation, the shuttle has passed over the net - albeit not at speed, but tumbling, typically after striking the net cord.

It [happens](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3671/1419) much more often if the net is either very fine, or has holes in it.

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://imgur.com/a/A8Vax ?

Comment: Yup, although in practice I believe it happens more with downwards drop/smash shots then upwards ones.